# Vertical Menu to stay open on hover then close when another is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical carousel menu that on two of the items opens to reveal sub menus. When you hover off the menu they close again and return to the normal menu state.

What I am looking for is a way for it to hover and remain open, then when another of any of the menus are hovered, they close and the hovered activates...

As I am using Joomla! as well it may be tricky to show the site etc but here is the JavaScript, and hopefully if more info is needed I can post it. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("ul li.parent").hover(function(){
     $(this).children("ul").slideDown(300);
     $(".contact-details-container p").fadeOut(200);
  },function(){
     $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300); 
     $(".contact-details-container p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<nav>

<ul class="menu-main">
<li class="item-108"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="item-111 deeper parent"><a href="#">History and Restoration</a>
<ul>
<li class="item-125"><a href="#">History</a></li>
<li class="item-126"><a href="#">The Kennaway Connection</a></li>
<li class="item-127"><a href="#">Previous Residents</a></li>
<li class="item-128"><a href="#">Restoration</a></li>
<li class="item-129"><a href="#">Sidmouth / Heritage Coast</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-112"><a href="#">Wedding Venue</a></li>
<li class="item-113"><a href="#">Hiring Rooms</a>       </li>
<li class="item-114 current active"><a href="#">Virtual Tour</a></li>
<li class="item-115"><a href="#">Art and Exhibitions</a></li>
<li class="item-116"><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
<li class="item-117 deeper parent"><a href="#">How Can I help</a>
<ul>
<li class="item-130"><a href="#">Friends of Kennaway House</a></li>
<li class="item-131"><a href="#">Volunteer Opportunities</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="item-118"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="item-119"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


</nav><!-- #nav -->

nav {
position:absolute;
top:190px;
left:0;
width:200px;
min-width:200px;
height:900px;
background:transparent;
z-index:9999;
}

#nav-bg {
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:80%;
background:<?php echo $contactscheme ?>;
}

nav:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:-10px;
right:0;
width:0;
border-top:10px solid transparent; /* height of right point */
border-right:200px solid #570C2A;
z-index:2;
}

nav:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:135px;
width:50px;
height:500px;
background:transparent;
-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(2deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
transform:rotate(2deg);
-webkit-box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
-moz-box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
z-index:-1;
}

.menu-main,
.menu-main ul {
max-height:900px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
font-size:1.2em;
background:#570C2A;
}

.menu-main li {
line-height:70px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.menu-main a {
display:block;
color:beige;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu-main a:hover, a:focus {
color:darkslategray;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:none;
outline:0 none;
-webkit-transition:250ms linear 0s;
-moz-transition:250ms linear 0s;
-o-transition:250ms linear 0s;
transition:250ms linear 0s;
}

.menu-main a:hover, a:focus {
color:beige;
text-shadow:1px -1px 14px beige;
}

.menu-main ul {
height:auto;
display:none;
}

.menu-main ul li {
font-size:0.6em;
line-height:30px;
}

.menu-main ul a {
background:transparent;
}

li.item-111.parent {
background:#486060;
line-height:22px;
padding:12px 3%;
}

/* -- sub menu styles for History and Restoration  -- */
.item-125, .item-126, .item-127, .item-128, .item-129 {
    background:#486060;
}

.item-125 {
    border-top:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

.item-129 {
    border-bottom:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

/* -- ===end=== -- */

.item-112 {
background:#557171;
}

.item-113 {
background:#663366;
}

.item-114 {
background:#86ACA8;
}

.item-115 {
background:#CD7F72;
}

.item-116 {
background:#BD8A16;
}

li.item-117.parent {
background:#C59F92;
line-height:50px;
padding:12px 3%;
}

/* -- sub menu styles for How Can I Help -- */
.item-130, .item-131 {
    background:#C59F92;
}

.item-130 {
    border-top:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

.item-131 {
    border-bottom:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

/* -- ===end=== -- */

.item-118 {
background:#869175;
}

.item-119 {
background:<?php echo $contactscheme ?>;
}
```

Comment: OK, added the HTML... Sorry for that This is the first time I've posted here after many months of lurking! haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hover function, why don't you add a new class that has the attribute `display:block`. Prior to setting this, call the close function for any open sub-menu that already has the selected class.

It may look something like this:

```
$(function () {
     $("ul.menu-main > li").hover(function () {
        //Don't do this again if the same menu is hovered
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            //Ensure any open sub-menu is closed.
            $("li.selected").children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
            $(".contact-details-container p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
            $("li.selected").removeClass('selected');

            //Open sub-menu
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown(300);
            $(".contact-details-container p").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Due to the way (I think) your menu is working, you shouldn't actually need the `display:block` attribute, but you will still need the class to identify the open submenus so you can apply your effects.

Comment: I shall give this a try, I've added the css if it's any help, but as I'm using Joomla! it can be a pain with javascript and the html for the menus etc.

Comment: The menu still seems to close when I hover off. It needs to stay open then close when another is hovered, unless I am not implementing it correctly, though I have just lifted the code you put in JDandChips.

Comment: In your developer toolbar (F12) is the new class been added to the element that your hovering? You probably want to remove the slideUp, as that will call effectively '.hide()' your element

Comment: Ok, so now the menu is staying open when hovering off. When I hover another menu item that also stays open and the previous remains open...

Am I adding anything to the css? Also the slide up needs to happen when the other menu item is hovered so removing that will effectively stop this? Sorry to be so helpless! :s

Comment: I've changed the example code. What should happen here is that any previously open sub-menu will be closed with the old `mouseout` function. Then your new one will open and remain open, until a new hover occurs. P.S. I don't really know how the `$(".contact-details-container p")` fits into the look of the menu, so this might need some tweaking to get it right.

Comment: Ah the $(".contact-details-container p") is a div that fades out when the menu slides down then fades back when the menu closes, I should have included that in the html!

Comment: Hmm, that might mean that the div will always be closed after the first hover happens. You could have a timeout that will close the sub-menu and give the div a chance to show after a certain time. I suppose this is something that you can work out after your get the menu working the way you want.

Comment: Ok, it's still not closing the menu when another is hovered... I'll send a link to the site personally. Can I do that?