# Close menu when another item is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a menu with two dropdowns. I need the dropdowns to open when the menu item is hovered over, but close if the other menu item is hovered over.

The problem I am having is getting the first dropdown to close if I hover over the second menu item.

Please see my fiddle here: http://www.bootply.com/uEKWCdNj4C

I've looked through other questions, and this one seems to possibly be of use, but I'm having trouble applying it to my situation: [Vertical Menu to stay open on hover then close when another is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454931/vertical-menu-to-stay-open-on-hover-then-close-when-another-is-hovered)

So I apologize if this is a duplicate...any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `slideup` on the open `ul` before calling `slidedown` on the current one. like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".nav-basic").hover(function () {
      $('ul.menu-applied').slideUp('medium');   
      $('ul.menu-basic').slideDown('medium');
  });
  $('ul.menu-basic').bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $('ul.menu-basic').slideUp('medium'); 
  }); 

  $(".nav-applied").hover(function () {
      $('ul.menu-basic').slideUp('medium');     
      $('ul.menu-applied').slideDown('medium');
  });
  $('ul.menu-applied').bind('mouseleave', function(){
     $('ul.menu-applied').slideUp('medium'); 
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

So set an `class="isHovered"` on the element that is hovered.
Set the boxes `class="isHovered"` aswell ..

If `hover` is called again , or lets say `mouseenter`, you check if `isHovered` is set on the current box and on the other box ... or iterate over any boxes there might be ...

You could aswell store the currently hovered element id in a variable and the box id. Then use these values. As JS is not multithreaded you can rely on the order of execution ...

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to update your script to call the slideUp function:

```
$(".nav-basic").hover(function () {
      $('ul.menu-basic').slideDown('medium');
     $('ul.menu-applied').slideUp('medium'); 
  });


  $(".nav-applied").hover(function () {    
      $('ul.menu-basic').slideUp('medium');
      $('ul.menu-applied').slideDown('medium');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use some optimization, but you could basically call `slideUp()` on all other `$(.menu-interior')` elements that are not of the target class:

Example: `$('.menu-interior:not(.menu-basic)').slideUp();`

See forked fiddle here: http://www.bootply.com/DZxktgUtjh

**Note:** This will close ANY other open menu, rather than having to hard-code all other classes when the menu grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $(".nav-basic").hover(function() {
         $('ul.menu-basic').slideToggle('medium');
     });

     $(".nav-applied").hover(function() {
         $('ul.menu-applied').slideToggle('medium');
     });

 });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.